# Add products to cart using \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface

Tags: magento2, addtocart, programmatically

I'm trying to add products to cart programmatically using **\Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface** since **\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart** is already deprecated. My code is successfully being inserted in **quote**, **quote_item** table and other tables. but it's not creating any entries in **quote_id_mask** table. I don't know what's lacking in my code.

Not also sure if it's the problem that's causing the product to not appear in the front end.

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\CartFactory $cartFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ItemFactory $quoteItemFactory,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterfaceFactory $cartInterface,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepositoryInterface,
    \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartItemInterfaceFactory $cartItemInterface,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManagerInterface,
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress $remoteAddress
){
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->cartFactory = $cartFactory;
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    $this->quoteItemFactory = $quoteItemFactory;
    $this->cartInterface = $cartInterface;
    $this->cartRepositoryInterface = $cartRepositoryInterface;
    $this->cartItemInterface = $cartItemInterface;
    $this->storeManagerInterface = $storeManagerInterface;
    $this->remoteAddress = $remoteAddress;
}

public function execute()
{
    $request_data = [
        ['sku' => 'product-sku', 'type' => 'sample']
    ];

    $cart = $this->cartInterface->create();
    $cart->setStoreId($this->storeManagerInterface->getStore()->getId());
    $cart->setRemoteIp($this->remoteAddress->getRemoteAddress());

    foreach($request_data as $request){
        $product = $this->productRepository->get($request['sku']);

        $item = $this->cartItemInterface->create();
        $item->setProduct($product);
        $item->setQty(1);

        $cart->addItem($item);

        $this->cartRepositoryInterface->save($cart);
    }

    die('test');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't actually test this but this [example](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/QuoteGraphQl/Model/Resolver/MergeCarts.php) might help you

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code to below.

```
foreach($request_data as $request){
        $product = $this->productRepository->get($request['sku']);

        $item = $this->cartItemInterface->create();
        $item->setProduct($product);
        $item->setQty(1);

        $cart->addItem($item);
    }
$this->cartRepositoryInterface->save($cart);
```